# Is GMAIL incorrectly failing SPF?

Tags: email, spf, google, dmarc

0365 mail users are [encouraged to use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/mt712724(v=exchg.150).aspx#FormYourSPF) include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all in their SPF record.

I have followed this guidance.  My company's spf record says:
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

the spf.protection.outlook.com record ends with include:spfa.protection.outlook.com -all
which ends with include:spfb.protection.outlook.com

Each of those includes has a set of CIDRs for IPs used by outlook.com when sending email.

However, I am getting DMARC reports from google.com indicating an SPF FAIL for an IP that is actually covered by one of the includes in the SPF record. I think this is incorrect, yet is happening frequently.

Here is an example:

```
    source_ip>104.47.117.233</source_ip>

<count>1</count>


-<policy_evaluated>

<disposition>none</disposition>

<dkim>pass</dkim>

<spf>fail</spf>
```

the rejected ip is part of ip4:104.47.0.0/17  which is part of the spfb.protection.outlook record:

spfb.protection.outlook.com. 394 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip6:2a01:111:f400::/48 ip4:23.103.128.0/19 ip4:23.103.198.0/23 ip4:65.55.88.0/24 **ip4:104.47.0.0/17** ip4:23.103.200.0/21 ip4:23.103.208.0/21 ip4:23.103.191.0/24 ip4:216.32.180.0/23 ip4:94.245.120.64/26 -all"

So, why is Google's email server treating this as an SPF fail?

This is not an isolated example - I receive frequent SPF fail notifications with respect to IPs included in the SPF record.

Comment: Is the mail in question sent directly from a regular office 365 mailbox? It would help to see the entire set of email headers on a rejected message. You can obfuscate the email addresses, but everything else should be left intact.

Comment: The mail is not being rejected.  DMARC evaluates DKIM and SPF, and if either pass, the mail is treated as 'pass'.  What I am trying to figure out is why the SPF is failing, when it shouldn't.  Also, these are outgoing emails, so I do not receive them, so cannot review their headers. The information about the SPF is coming to me via DMARC aggregation reports sent to me by DMARC participant mailservers - including Google and Yahoo. I have included an extract from one of those in the OP.  And, yes, the outgoing mail is being sent from regular 0365 mailboxes.

Comment: Please help, I think i'm asking similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/971035/dmarc-why-do-i-receive-failed-spf-or-dkim-authentication-reports-for-forwarders)

Answer (score 6):

I have figured it out. Not surprisingly, it was me misinterpreting the report, not Google getting their DMARC implementation wrong :)

The SPF result in the policy evaluated section that I was being confused by (copy posted in OP) is the DMARC evaluated SPF result *after* considering alignment.

This quote [here](https://dmarc.org/wiki/FAQ) explains the issue:

> Please note that the SPF and DKIM results in the auth_results are raw results, regardless of Identifier Alignment; he results of the DMARC evaluation with Identifier Alignment are in the policy_evaluated section.

I checked the rest of the record and found that the *raw* results for the same record were, correctly, SPF pass.

So, what the DMARC report was telling me was that, while the SPF result was indeed from outlook.com (and hence was a raw 'pass') the return path header did not match my sending domain, which produces a DMARC *evaluation* SPF fail.  Another reference [here](https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/what-is-alignment/).

**Basically, do not attempt to read the XML reports directly - they are hard for humans!**  I found [this](https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-xml/) DMARC xml parser which does a fabulous job of allowing you to clearly see what the DMARC report is trying to tell you.