# dmarc. Why do I receive failed SPF or DKIM authentication reports for forwarders?

Tags: email, spf, dkim, amazon-ses, dmarc

I set _dmarc to see my email authentication reports (in case it fails).

like that

```
"v=DMARC1;p=quarantine;pct=100;rua=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com"
```

And I receive these reports form Google.

a report I receive my emails are good, because they are comming from AWS SES and all configured fine, it comes like that

```
<disposition>none</disposition>
<dkim>pass</dkim>
<spf>pass</spf>
```

BUT sometimes I get records like this

```
<record>
  <row>
    <source_ip>209.85.220.41</source_ip>
    <count>1</count>
    <policy_evaluated>
    <disposition>none</disposition>
      <dkim>pass</dkim>
      <spf>fail</spf>
    </policy_evaluated>
  </row>
  <identifiers>
    <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
  </identifiers>
  <auth_results>
    <dkim>
      <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
      <result>pass</result>
      <selector>xxx</selector>
    </dkim>
    <dkim>
      <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
      <result>pass</result>
      <selector>gggxxx</selector>
    </dkim>
    <spf>
      <domain>gmail.com</domain>
      <result>pass</result>
    </spf>
  </auth_results>
</record>
```

And I understand that someone has forwarded my email but without overwriting headers and this someone was `gmail`.

Why gmail doesn't overwrite headers and why should I care about forwarding at all?
They only suppose to send me emails when it is my problem, right?

Am I confusing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a few assumptions here:

> **Why gmail doesn't overwrite headers...?**

Server-side / automated forwards are usually behaving this way: keeping the original sender in the `header.from` and changing the `envelope from` (`bounce-address`) to the service forwarding the email. When an aligned `DKIM` signature is present and as long as signed fields are not altered, `DKIM` will successfully authenticate the message and `DMARC` will pass. If no DKIM signature is found, `DMARC` will fail.

> **They only suppose to send me emails when it is my problem, right?**

No. `DMARC` policy records containing a `rua` tag are requesting receiving servers to periodically send an aggregate report of all email received that was sent on behalf of the domain in the `header.from` field. The receiving server should not make assumptions (whose fault it is) on what is the reason for a specific check to fail (in this case misalignment of domains used in `header.from` and `envelope from`).

Comment: Gigantic thanks. You  saved me.